# Converted html to pdf throwing casting exception in my attempt to check it

Tags: c#, itext7

I am using iText7 to generate a pdf file in C#.  I need to check each 
block of `elements` of my html file\content that I am converting.

To do so, I wrote the following code and added a "page break" to `html` content.

```
List<IElement> elements = (List<IElement>)HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(html);

for (int k = 0; k < elements.Count; k++)
{
    cell.Add((IBlockElement)elements[k]);
}
```

However, when I run the above code, I receive a casting error for `IBlockElement`:

> Unable to cast object of type 'iText.Html2pdf.Attach.Impl.Layout.HtmlPageBreak' to type 'iText.Layout.Element.IBlockElement'

So, my question is - How can I check the content of `element[k]`?

Comment: that's a bit of an odd question.. are you familiar with debugging and breakpoints?

Comment: yes, I am a bit familiar, I guess you mean I should add css instead of page break, like the following: <div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>

Comment: no no.. I'm asking whether you setup a break point and debugged this execution in your IDE - so that you can see what `elements` instance contains.  It's one thing to ask for what `IBlockElement` is, I could point you to the documentation for that, but the contents of that type, and the concrete type for that matter, are going to be the results of whatever you converted here.

Comment: I already added break point to my html script and I can find it successfully through the following if clause :  if ((elements[k].GetType().ToString() == "iText.Html2pdf.Attach.Impl.Layout.HtmlPageBreak") , but the issue is that when I want to add the block which contains break point to cell I will get casting error

Comment: the error is : Unable to cast object of type 'iText.Html2pdf.Attach.Impl.Layout.HtmlPageBreak' to type 'iText.Layout.Element.IBlockElement'.

Comment: I looked into that type (on the very poorly maintained documentation site) and doesn't inherit that interface (which is of course why the casting exception occurs.  It's still unclear to me what you mean by checking the contents, or 'each block'.  Can you clarify what you are checking for - the purpose of this check? are you just manually trying to determine whether the elements converted over? does something about the pdf document look odd? what are you actually attempting to do in `cells` and `elements`?

Comment: here is a link to the [documentation site](https://api.itextpdf.com/pdfHTML/dotnet/2.1.5/classi_text_1_1_html2pdf_1_1_attach_1_1_impl_1_1_layout_1_1_html_page_break.html#pub-methods)

Comment: I have generated a pdf file which has header and footer and some html tables which is loaded from database. My issue is that I need to be able to use page break while cells of first column of all tables should be in one page. Currently I used SetKeepTogether(true) for cells of the tables, but page break does not work.

Comment: (sorry for the OT, but @BrettCaswell, feel free to email me on how we could improve our documentation. my email is andre.lemos at itext's domain).

Comment: remove that, we'll do a chat instead [discussion chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201292/too-broad-question-refiner)

Comment: @Brett could you provide feedback on the documentation? Edit - André beat me to it. :)